# Join without Cartesian output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes, df1, df2,  where I would like to join on two different table names. The goal is to concatenate the tables based on values that match in the site and id column without a Cartesian output. I am getting a final output with an exponentially increased records number.

**Data**

df1

```
site planq tr   unit    alias   energy
ny   q1 22      du1     du_cc   10
ny   q1 22      du1     du_cc   10
ny   q1 22      du1     du_cc   10
dc   q2 22      aa1     aa_cc   8
dc   q2 22      aa1     aa_cc   8
dc   q2 22      aa1     aa_cc   8
dc   q2 22      aa1     aa_cc   8
```

df2

```
serial  sku type    reason  id
34444   d1  d       ok      ny
34444   d1  d       ok      ny
34444   d1  d       ok      ny
555     a1  a       np      dc
555     a1  a       np      dc
```

**Desired**

```
site    planqtr unit    alias   energy  serial  sku type    reason  id
ny      q1 22   du1     du_cc   10      34444   d1  d       ok      ny
ny      q1 22   du1     du_cc   10      34444   d1  d       ok      ny
ny      q1 22   du1     du_cc   10      34444   d1  d       ok      ny
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       555     a1  a       np      dc
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       555     a1  a       np      dc
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       NaN     NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       NaN     NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
```

**Doing**

```
join = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left',left_on= ['site'], right_on = ['id'])
```

However, I am getting a final output with an exponentially increased records number. I am unsure why the output is showing thousands of rows of outputs. Any suggestions or advice is appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't merge function have `left_on` as `site` and `right_on` as `id` because df1 has `site` and df2 has `id`?

Comment: right, let me fix. Even after I fix this, it still gives a cartesian output. I will try

Comment: And, you are getting increased number of records which is correct. In `df1` there are 3 rows with `ny` and in `df2 ` there are `3`. When those rows will be merged, data will be populated as a catesian product and it will create 9 entries. Same goes for `dc`, that will result in `4 x 2` = 8 rows.

Comment: Your output is much bigger than expected because your joining key is not unique, so you get all combinations of rows. See my answer for a concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1.reset_index().join(df2.reset_index())# if it has no index
```

Or

```
df1.join(df2 ,lsuffix='lft', rsuffix='rght')# if it has index



  site planq  tr unit  alias  energy   serial  sku type reason   id
0   ny    q1  22  du1  du_cc      10  34444.0   d1    d     ok   ny
1   ny    q1  22  du1  du_cc      10  34444.0   d1    d     ok   ny
2   ny    q1  22  du1  du_cc      10  34444.0   d1    d     ok   ny
3   dc    q2  22  aa1  aa_cc       8    555.0   a1    a     np   dc
4   dc    q2  22  aa1  aa_cc       8    555.0   a1    a     np   dc
5   dc    q2  22  aa1  aa_cc       8      NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
6   dc    q2  22  aa1  aa_cc       8      NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Comment: ok thank you @wwnde, but don't I have to include the column names in which I am joining on as well?

Comment: Correct, you dont need column names if you are doing a join, basically appends using index.

Comment: ok thank you, I've tried both solutions but the output says: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['id'], dtype='object')

Comment: Include suffix. Learn to explore some of these errors. In such cases, search the documentation and you will see `DataFrame.join(other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='', sort=False)[source]` and explanation for each input

Comment: `df1.join(df2 ,lsuffix='', rsuffix='rght')` Note you can leave the left as `''` and then after that drop the one suffixed right.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

you can try via `concat()` and concatinate them `axis=1`:

```
out=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

output of `out`:

```
site    planqtr unit    alias   energy  serial  sku type    reason  id
ny      q1 22   du1     du_cc   10      34444   d1  d       ok      ny
ny      q1 22   du1     du_cc   10      34444   d1  d       ok      ny
ny      q1 22   du1     du_cc   10      34444   d1  d       ok      ny
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       555     a1  a       np      dc
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       555     a1  a       np      dc
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       NaN     NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       NaN     NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to perform a join? This usually requires the joining key to be unique. I have the feeling what you're looking for is a concatenation:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```